# Accessing data on local machine from remote kernel

Tags: front-end, import, kernel, remote-access

I have a remote kernel on a server that I would like to use to process some data. The connection works, i.e, I'm able to use the local front end and the remote kernel. However, I cannot figure out how should I access from the remote kernel the data that are on my local machine.

I thought I could simply use `Import` with the path to my computer and to the file that I want to import, but I didn't succeed. Something like:

```
Import["computerName@ip_address:/Users/myUserName/Desktop/data.txt","Table"]
```

> Import::nffil: File not found during Import. >>

Comment: Import the data in the frontend and do DistributeDefinitions?

Comment: @Ajasja I looked at the documentation for `DistributeDefinitions`, but I don't get it how I should use it. For instance, `f[n_] := PrimeQ[2^n - 1]` and then `DistributeDefinitions[f];` should transport the definition to all kernels. But when I try f[2] from the FE connected to the remote kernel the output is f[2] instead of True.

Comment: Ahh, sorry I thought they were slave kernels (for parallel computations), but you have the FE connected directly to a remote kernel. Then you have to share a disk or a drive or copy your data on some webserver...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some fiddling I found a solution to directly access my local files from the remote kernel via SSH. If *localuser* is the user name on the machine that runs the front end on which are also the data you want to import from the remote kernel and *111.111.111.11* is the IP address of the same machine, you just need to type:

```
Import["!ssh localuser@111.111.111.11 cat /Users/localuser/Desktop/data.txt", "Table"]
```

To make this work smoothly you first need to set up public key authentication over SSH.
Let *remoteuser* be the user name on the machine that runs the remote kernel and let *222.222.222.22* be the IP address of the remote machine.

On your local machine launch the terminal:

1. Generate a public key:

   - ssh-keygen -t rsa
2. Ok, when asks to save it in:

   - .ssh/id_rsa
3. Press return when asks for passphrase.
4. Press return againg when asks for passphrase.
5. Copy the public key on the remote machine:

   - scp id_rsa.pub remoteuser@222.222.222.22:/home/remoteuser
6. Connect to remote machine:

   - ssh remoteuser@222.222.222.22
7. Append the public key (previously copied from local machine to remote machine) to the list of authorized keys:

   - cat id_rsa.pub >> .ssh/authorized_keys
8. Generate a public key on the remote machine:

   - ssh-keygen -t rsa
9. Ok, when asks to save it in:
   -.ssh/id_rsa
10. Press return when asks for passphrase.
11. Press return againg when asks for passphrase.
12. Copy the public key on the local machine:

    - scp id_rsa.pub localuser@111.111.111.11:/Users/localuser
13. Exit from remote server: CTRL+D
14. Append the public key (previously copied from remote machine into local home) to the list of authorized keys:

    - cat id_rsa.pub >> .ssh/authorized_keys

Comment: Nice hack :) +1

Comment: Is there a similar solution for the `Export`?

Comment: @ybeltukov I don't know if it works, but did you try to follow all the steps above and then simply `Export["!ssh localuser@111.111.111.11 cat /Users/localuser/Desktop/newfile.txt", data, "TSV"]`, where data is the dataset you want to export?

Comment: @VLC This doesn't work for me with `Export["!ssh localuser@111.111.111.11 cat /folder/newfile.txt", data]` it produces the output : `OutputStream["!ssh localuser@111.111.111.11 cat /folder/newfile.txt", 236]` but actually no newfile.txt is created on my local machine from the remote kernel.