# How to test if file exists on the front end machine?

Tags: front-end, files-and-directories

When using a remote Mathematica kernel, how can you test if a file exists on the local front end machine? Of course `FileExistsQ` cannot be used in this scenario, because it only works on the kernel file system.

There are some undocumented functions in the `FrontEnd` context, which may do the trick with `FrontEndExecute`:

```
Names["FrontEnd`*File*"]
```

yields

```
{"FrontEnd`FileBrowse", "FrontEnd`Filename", "FrontEnd`FileName", "FrontEnd`FindFileOnPath", "FrontEnd`ToFileName"}
```

Comment: Just curious: If you can't open a file using a kernel running on a remote machine what use does it have to know whether a file exists on a local machine?

Comment: Test if a file has been correctly installed on the front end machine.

Comment: But what use would that have for the running kernel? Are you perhaps comparing Mathematica installations on FrontEnd and remote PCs?

Comment: I agree with @Sjoerd that maybe we are missing some details of your problem here. Generally speaking, it seems to me that the remote kernel must have access to your local file to do the check. Importing and exporting results from remote kernels suffer from similar problems, and some questions about them have cropped up before (see [(18016)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18016/27951) and [(19394)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19394/27951)), with limited success, and always requiring the remote kernel to have access to the local system.

Comment: Upon manipulating front end options with `SetOptions[$FrontEnd` (e.g., `NotebookBrowseDirectory`), the kernel can make sure that a valid value is set.

Comment: Can't you use `CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, NotebookAutoSave]` for that?

Comment: I guess that worked?  Cool.  :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't have any kernels running on a remote machine so I cannot be sure of how this is handled, but I think it has as good a chance as any of working.

A file that exists:

```
MathLink`CallFrontEnd[MLFS`FileByteCount["A:\\foo.txt"]]
```

> ```
> 16
> ```

A file that does not exist:

```
MathLink`CallFrontEnd[MLFS`FileByteCount["A:\\bar.txt"]]
```

> ```
> $Failed
> ```

Other commands in the same context that may prove useful:

```
Names["MLFS`*"]
```

> ```
> {"MLFS`Close", "MLFS`CopyDirectory", "MLFS`CopyFile", "MLFS`CreateDirectory", 
> "MLFS`DeleteDirectory", "MLFS`DeleteFile", "MLFS`FileByteCount", "MLFS`FileDate", 
> "MLFS`FileNames", "MLFS`FileType", "MLFS`Get", "MLFS`OpenAppend", "MLFS`OpenRead", 
> "MLFS`OpenWrite", "MLFS`Put", "MLFS`PutAppend", "MLFS`Read", "MLFS`RenameDirectory", 
> "MLFS`RenameFile", "MLFS`SetFileDate", "MLFS`SetStreamPosition", "MLFS`StreamPosition", 
> "MLFS`WriteString"}
> ```

Found via:

- [What is the complete list of valid FrontEnd Packet types?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13451/121)

Comment: It works. The "MLFS`FileType`" is another good option.

Comment: What `MLFS` is except of the fact that it introduces some functions that may be run by FE?

Comment: @Kuba  I don't know.  Maybe MathLink File System?  +shrug+

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Makes sense ;)

Comment: @Kuba BTW did you come here looking for a solution to [(108640)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/108640/121)?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No, I have to have things done so I'm using some specific workarounds and left that question open. I came here because I was looking for FE equivalent for FindFile. I know I can do `FileNames[fileName, ToFileName/@AbsoluteCurrentValue[$FrontEnd, "StyleSheetPath"]]` but it isn't the fastest solution, fast enough to use though, I was just curious.

Comment: @Kuba if you haven't found it yet I updated the front-end packet types to include ``FrontEnd`FindFileOnPath`` which is what you want.