# How to unlock a stylesheet which is not needed anymore by the FrontEnd

Tags: bugs, front-end, files-and-directories, stylesheet, windows

**Bug introduced in 10.3.0 or earlier and fixed in 11.1**

**Bug reproduced on Win but not on Mac**

Reply from WRI Support:

> [...] This indeed seems to be an issue with the Frontend on Windows and I have alerted the development team about this.
>
> Unfortunately I do not have a work around at this moment other than manually deleting it (and I understand that is not something you are interested in). [...]

---

#### Problem:

So, if your notebook has a *private stylesheet* and this stylesheet has a *parent stylesheet*, you can't delete the parent, in the same FE session, even after the notebook is closed.

Something like Default.nb (private) and  Core.nb (its parent).

#### Implications

If your application have a more complex StyleSheets system and you want to incorporate some kind of automatic updating of the app, you will have a bad time replacing Package/FrontEnd/Stylesheets part.

#### Minimal example:

We are going to create a notebook, its private stylesheet and the stylesheet that this parent inherits from.

```
dir = FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "directory"}];
CreateDirectory@dir;
SetDirectory@dir;


nb = Notebook[{
    Cell[BoxData@RowBox@{"1", "+", "1"}, "Input"]},
   StyleDefinitions -> FileNameJoin[{dir, "privateStyles.nb"}]
   ];

privateStyles = Notebook[{
    Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "defaultStyles.nb"]],
    Cell[StyleData["Input"], FontSize -> 25]
    }];

defaultStyles = Notebook[{
    Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]],
    Cell[StyleData["Input"], FontColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 1]]
    }
   ];

Export["defaultStyles.nb", defaultStyles];
Export["privateStyles.nb", privateStyles];
Export["testNb.nb", nb]; (*this will give an error but it doesn't matter*)

NotebookOpen[
 FileNameJoin[{dir, "testNb.nb"}]
];

NotebookClose @ %;

DeleteFile /@ FileNames["*"]
```

> DeleteFile::privv: Privilege violation for file or directory defaultStyles.nb. >>
>
> ```
> {$Failed, Null, Null}
> ```

---

As you can see, the parent stylesheet can be easily deleted. Yet, its parent can't.

#### Question

Is there any way to proceed that doesn't involve closing the FrontEnd?

#### Edit by Mike H

This appears to be an OS or version specific problem:

[image]

Comment: Using 10.3.1 on OS X 10.10.5 all stylesheets were deleted

Comment: The problem appears in 10.1.0 under Windows 7.  Which version are you running?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard 10.3.1,  have you tried in earlier releases?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard considering the reply from WRI I've included, can we call it a bug?

Comment: Smells like a bug to you, smells like a bug to me, and support doesn't think it should do that.  Pretty easy decision. :^)

Comment: @Kuba This returns `{Null, Null, Null}` for me in 11.1 on Windows.

Comment: @ihojnicki you are right, I may have checked on an older build. Have to clean up my installations. p.s. it would have a very positive effect to send bug fixes reports as promised by the support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to drop this topic from an unanswered stack:

> Bug fixed in Mathematica V11.1